# debug on public IP address running ASP.NET in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, kestrel

I wonder if is it possible to debug an app ASP.net (here a web api) by using public IP address. Indeed, it is mandatory for me to use the IP public of my dev computer to send data to my web api (data are coming from an another website request).

Edit :

Visual studio seems to only use localhost. I have tried to forward port but this doesn't work. It seems it is the normal behavior of visual studio.

Comment: You are automatically using the public IP address of your machine.  You are using IP routing to make a connection from the local machine to public machine.  Based on the Destination IP address a connection will be made over the internet (public).

Comment: Visual studio seems to only use localhost. I have tried to forward port but this doesn't work. It seems it is the normal behavior of visual studio. I don't understand your answer but i don't speak very well english.

Comment: There should be not difference on testing your application on the local machine (localhost) or a remote machine except if the connection is blocked or you do not have the credentials to make the connecton.  You issue has nothing to do with VS.  An ASP.Net project consists of the client and server application A HTTP connection is made between the client and server. Connection is made over the Ethernet.  There are 7 Network layers.  The client and server use the application layer.  The connection is made on the transport layer (over ethernet).  You are having an issue with the ethernet, not app.

Comment: With java and tomcat, i have no problems. So it is linked to the ASP.NET technology. Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: Usually in these cases issue is either a default HTTP header that is is wrong or missing.  The header in Net are different from java/tomcat.  The other issue is if you are using a HTTPS (secure) which uses TLS for authentication.  The TLS often fails.  Adding followng static method at beginning of app often solves issue : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: For whatever web project you are on, change its project setting to use full IIS on your Windows machine, and then you can change the site bindings there to accept external traffic, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html You cannot easily do the same when using IIS Express (but you can if you insist with some extra setup).

Comment: That exactly that I want. So I have setup IIS in windows and in visual studio. When i launch IIS and i test in postman, i have this error with using localhost. 

POST http://localhost/8080/api/values
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

If I use public IP address, i have timeout. So I think IIS is not well setup. But I am no able to set the right configuration.

In any case, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have fixed my issue by using this :

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti

Comment: For older Visual Studio versions, you can use the NgRok extension that will give you a public IP for your Web Api ( https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidProthero.NgrokExtensions )

Answer (score 0):

For older Visual Studio versions (2015, 2017, 2019), you can use the NgRok VS extension that will give you a public IP for your Web Api project ( https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidProthero.NgrokExtensions )